# How do i extract merged data and put them into different worksheets?

Tags: excel, vba

How do i use excel vba to extract merged data selectively(not manually clicking and copying from the excel sheet and also not specifically listing the range of the data that i want to copy. What i want is in a way such that the programme extract the entire row that has the same type of name from column F to column H for example Martin_1,Martin_2 and Martin _3 respectively for different names(John, Charlie) and copy and paste them to a new worksheet.

[image]

**Put the extracted data into 3 different sheets namely index 1, index 2 and index 3 as shown below**
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is my attempted code:

```
dim i as integer
dim lastmartinrow as integer
dim c as string
dim j as integer
dim lastjohnrow as integer
dim b as string
dim k as integer
dim lastcharlierow as integer
dim a as string

for i = 1 to lastmartinrow
Set c = .Find("Martin_1","Martin_2",Martin_3" LookIn:=xlValues)
If c Is Nothing Then
'find the last row has the same "Martin_1","Martin_2","Martin_3") 
'copy the entire rows from 1 to lastmartinrow and paste it to a new worksheet("Index1").name
for j = lastmartinrow + 1 to lastjohnrow
Set b = .Find("John_1","John_2","John_3" LookIn:=xlValues)
If b Is Nothing Then
'find the last row has the same "John_1","John_2","John_3") 
'copy the entire rows from lastmartinrow + 1 to lastjohnrow and paste it to a new worksheet("Index2").name
for k = lastjohnrow + 1 to lastcharlierow
Set a = .Find("Charlie_1","Charlie_2",Charlie_3" LookIn:=xlValues)
If a Is Nothing Then
'find the last row has the same Charlie_1","Charlie_2",Charlie_3") 
'copy the entire rows from lastjohnrow + 1 to lastcharlierow and paste it to a new worksheet("Index3").name
```

error for the updated code 
[image]
Because previously i didnt save the spreadsheet when it crashed so this is the new sheet1 i am using right now..
[![enter image description here][6]][6]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a generic code, It will copy all the matching values(John,Marin,Charlie etc) present in F to H columns and paste it in Index3 sheet. It will not copy values with single row means which are not matching with any other row(immediately after that).

```
Sub UpdateVal()
    Static count As Long
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim aRow As Long
    Dim a As Long
    Dim b As Long
    Dim selectRange As Range
    j = 2
    iRow = 1
    LastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count
    While iRow < LastLine + 1
        a = iRow + 1
        b = iRow + 17 ' Max Group Size with Same name in F to H column
        count = 1
        If Cells(iRow, "F").Value = "Martin1" Then
            sheetname = "Index1"
        ElseIf Cells(iRow, "F").Value = "John1" Then
            sheetname = "Index2"
        Else
            sheetname = "Index3"
        End If
        For aRow = a To b
            If Cells(iRow, "F") = Cells(aRow, "F") And Cells(iRow, "G") = Cells(aRow, "G") And Cells(iRow, "H") = Cells(aRow, "H") Then
                count = count + 1
            Else
                Set selectRange = Range("A" & iRow & ":J" & aRow - 1)
                selectRange.Copy
                indexrowcount = Sheets(sheetname).UsedRange.Rows.count
                Sheets(sheetname).Range("A" & indexrowcount).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                iRow = iRow + count
                Exit For
           End If
        Next aRow
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: that is an error with the code such that when i run it, it will cause the excel to crash

Comment: Obviously, I didn't give the code to crash your excel. what error are you getting?

Comment: 17 rows for sheet1

Comment: instead of screen shot, can u please add plain text?

Comment: u mean description of the screenshot also?

Comment: No i am talking about the excel data which contains 17 rows.

Comment: i just posted the picture of my sheet1

Comment: I will not be able to copy text from picture. I want to test code on your data.

Comment: Try the updated code. I have tested it with your excel data. It is working fine.

Comment: do we have to dim anything like sheetname,indexrowcount or something else? And do we have to change the sheetname into different sheetnames like sheetname1 ,sheetname2 sheetname3 for different indexes?Because i still faced the same error that i mentioned as shown on the above post...

Comment: Without Dim it will work. And obviously we are using Index1 , Index2 and Index3 sheets in code so all these sheets should be there in your excel.

Comment: i have already created the index1,index 2 and index 3 worksheet before running the macro but it just shows the same error ;(

Comment: It should be Index1(with capital I) and similarly for Index2 & Index3. You can see the sheet names in code. Mention as it is.

Comment: yup i did put the captical I in my indexes worksheet name and same error still ocurred as shown on my above post

Comment: Delete the existing content from Index1, Index2 and Index3 and then execute the code. I thinks existing content is there in these sheets, so it is appending.

Comment: to make sure there is no content, i went to delete and create the index 1 to index3 worksheet but same problem still persists

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207244/discussion-between-naveen-arora-and-cena).