# How to solve the "program not responding error" when i extract data with same name in a column and put them into different worksheets?

Tags: excel, vba

Based on the earlier thread that i posted, [How do i extract merged data and put them into different worksheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60069416/how-do-i-extract-merged-data-and-put-them-into-different-worksheets) Everything seems fine until my program encounter the

> "program not responding error"

which I think is due to using

```
Sheets(sheetname).UsedRange.Rows.count
```

(because of deleting and clearing rows) which cause this to happen. Based on other thread discussions, I tried to use this instead

```
Cells(Sheets("SheetName").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlup).Row
```

(better options as suggested by others) but it didnt give me the result that I want which is as shown below. So how do I modify my below code to solve the program not responding error in this case and still get the ideal scenario as shown below?

[image]

Put the extracted data into 3 different sheets namely index 1, index 2 and index 3 as shown below

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
   Sub UpdateVal()
    Static count As Long
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim aRow As Long
    Dim a As Long
    Dim b As Long
    Dim selectRange As Range
    dim lastline as integer
    dim sheetname as string
    dim indexrowcount as integer
    dim wb as workbook
    dim ws as worksheet
    set wb= activeworkbook
    set ws=wb.sheets(Index)
    j = 2
    iRow = 1
    LastLine = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count
    While iRow < LastLine + 1
        a = iRow + 1
        b = iRow + 17 ' Max Group Size with Same name in F to H column
        count = 1
        If ws.Cells(iRow, "F").Value = "Martin1" Then
            sheetname = "Index1"
        ElseIf ws.Cells(iRow, "F").Value = "John1" Then
            sheetname = "Index2"
        Else
            sheetname = "Index3"
        End If
        For aRow = a To b
            If ws.Cells(iRow, "F") = ws.Cells(aRow, "F") And ws.Cells(iRow, "G") = ws.Cells(aRow, "G") And ws.Cells(iRow, "H") = ws.Cells(aRow, "H") Then
                count = count + 1
            Else
                Set selectRange = Range("A" & iRow & ":J" & aRow - 1)
                selectRange.Copy
                indexrowcount = Sheets(sheetname).UsedRange.Rows.count
                Sheets(sheetname).Range("A" & indexrowcount).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                iRow = iRow + count
                Exit For
           End If
        Next aRow
    Wend
```

Comment: Ops, just updated my code

Comment: If Excel is not responding that means (in almost any case) that the VBA code is still running. Check your loops and how many times they run. Nested loops can easily run a very long time. What is the value of `LastLine` (so we can know how many times your loop will run)?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ i waited quite awhile for the program to run but it still shows no sign of responding...my value of lastline is 17

Comment: Probably not **directly** solving your issue, but using [`Explicit`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/9758194) sheet references **will** at least help! Without looking in depth, maybe you are creating an endless loop. Stepping through your code using `F8` might help (keep a close eye on your variables).

Comment: @JvdV sorry, i am quite new to vba may i know what is that and how do i go about doing that?

Comment: I would step through line by line and check that the iRow increment is hit, otherwise it will be an infinite loop.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav my value of irow is 18 tho..

Comment: Technically this code works but is just that when i tried to rerun the code by deleting and pasting data again without exiting the workbook, the error will occur.

Comment: @cena see the answer posted.  Your irow is only updated in one condition of the if statement, so could not be hit.

Comment: @cena If you *"waited quite awhile"* then you waited not long enough ;) But if your code is not solid it also can be that you have an endless loop. Which is more likely sicne your `LastLine` is only 17 it should be finishen in less than 1 min. Go through your code step by step using F8 and check the values of your variables in each step. So you see what actually happens (maybe some variables never increase or if statements have a different reslut than you thought).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that your `Implicit` sheet references could be the culprit. As mentioned in my comment, `Implicit` references will refer to the currently active sheet, or `ActiveSheet`.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/9758194) post on how to avoid that. When you studied that post, you should have a `Worksheet` variables, for exmple `ws` to refer to.

Right now, `If Cells(iRow, "F") = Cells(aRow, "F") And Cells(iRow, "G") = Cells(aRow, "G") And Cells(iRow, "H") = Cells(aRow, "H") Then` could be `TRUE` on any `ActiveSheet` with all empty cells for example. That way you will never hit `FALSE` and `iRow` **never** gets incremented > **Endless loop** > **Your error**!

Comment: ah so i should be using  Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Set ws = Worksheets("Index") after that replace activesheet with ws?

Comment: @cena, and then use it with `ws.Cells(x,y)` etc.

Comment: but now when i did that, the error doesnt occur but the data are not pasted on index 1,index 2 and index 3 from the original data that is at index

Comment: i updated my code but im not sure what else am i missing here after adding ws. and dim wb as workbook, dim ws=worksheets("index")

Comment: @cena, looking at your code you haven't yet quite grasped the idea of setting a `Worksheet` variable correctly. You must assign a **valid** worksheet to the variable, right now I doubt your code would even compile since `Index` is an empty variable (and should not be used as a variable name in the first place) > `Set ws = wb.Worksheets("YourWorksheetName")`